# React Post operation on submit not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code snippet I developed but onSubmit does not seems to work.Can anyone help me

```
const initialValues={
id:"",
title:"",
director:"",
actor:"",
genre:""
}
const options = [
{
label: "Romance",
value: "romance",
},
{
label: "Drama",
value: "drama",
},
{
label: "Thriller",
value: "thriller",
},
{
label: "Crime",
value: "crime",
},
{
label: "Comedy",
value: "comedy",
},
{
label: "Western",
value: "western",
},
];
const AddMovie = () => {
const [title,setTitle]=useState(" ")
const [director,setDirector]=useState(" ")
const [actor,setActor]=useState(" ")
const [genre,setGenre]=useState('')
const [movieList,setMovieList]=useState(initialValues);
const handleGenre=(event)=>{
setGenre(event.target.value)
```

`}
  const onTitleChange=(e)=>{
    setTitle(e.target.value)
  }
    const onDirectorChange=(e)=>{
    setDirector(e.target.value)
  }
    const onActorChange=(e)=>{
    setActor(e.target.value)
  }
  const onTextChange=(event)=>{
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }
  const onSubmit=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("wete")
      const movieObject={
        title:title,
        director:director,
        actor:actor,
        genre:genre
      }
      setMovieList(movieObject)
      axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/add', movieObject)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data)
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            });
            console.log(movieList)
        setMovieList({ title: '', director: '' ,actor:'',genre:''})
  }
  return (
     <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
      }}
       onSubmit={onSubmit}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
      className="container"
    >
      <div>
      <Typography variant='h3' className="heading">Add Movie</Typography>
        <div className="input-container">
        <TextField
          required
          id="outlined-required"
          label="Movie"
          value={title}
          placeholder="Movie name"
          className="input"
          onChange={onTitleChange}
        />
        
      
     
         <TextField
          required
          id="outlined-required"
          label="Director"
          placeholder="Director"
          className="input"
          onChange={onTextChange}
        />
        <TextField
          required
          className="input"
          id="outlined-required"
          label="Actor"
          placeholder="Actor"
          onChange={onTextChange}
          
        />
         <div className="input-select">
    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>    
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Genre</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select"
    value={genre}
    label="Genre" 
    onChange={handleGenre}
  >
  {options.map((option,index)=>(
     <MenuItem key={index}value={option.value}>{option.label}</MenuItem>
  ))}
    {/* <MenuItem value={"Action"}>Action</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"Romance"}>Romance</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"Drama"}>Drama</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={"Horror"}>Horror</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"Thriller"}>Thriller</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"Western"}>Western</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={"Comedy"}>Comedy</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"Crime"}>Crime</MenuItem> */}
  </Select>
  </FormControl>
  </div>
        
      </div>

      </div>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" >Add</Button>
      
    </Box>
  )
}

export default AddMovie
</pre>`

Comment: _"does not seems to work"_ is not the best way to describe your problem. What is the expected result? What happens instead? Do you receive any error messages? It's worth reading [how to ask questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The onSubmit function is actually attached to the form element in the Box component, not the Box component itself.

In your code, you have correctly added the onSubmit function to the Box component. However, you also need to update the Button component to **type submit** so that clicking on it triggers the **onSubmit** function attached to the form element.

Here's the updated code for the Button component:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">Add</Button>
```

With this change, clicking on the "Add" button should trigger the onSubmit function and perform the form submission.